# Move ONLY Diff changes in the branch in GIT

Tags: git, gitlab

We have a scenario where we need to move the branches(A,B,C) merged to master into another branch, let's say Branch X1. How can I only merge the diff between X1 and master and ignore all other changes in master?

For ex, developer 1 and 2 worked in A.java with branches A & B and both merged into master. If I try to merge the branch B into X1, the changes from A also is moved. Is there anyway for me to move only the Branch B diff?

**EDIT:** The branch X1 is used to deploy in Production and we use master to deploy into UAT environment. Branch A and B both deployed to UAT but client only agrees to move B into X1 as A is still testing in progress. Now the problem is while creating branch B from master the changes from A also reflected into that branch. This is why we face conflict and need a way to only move changes made in Branch B. Hope this clears.

Comment: Your question is semehow unclear. You have A, B, C merged in master, ok. Then a new branch X1? Why dont't you just merge the branch B directly into the new X1? Why is there a change from A. Please rewrite your question ... I personally do not understand it.

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName Edited the question. Please check.

Comment: I don't know how much commits you have ... but you could manually revert the ones from A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to resolve this would be to **cherry-pick** the commits from branch `B` onto a new branch off `X1`, let's say `X1/hotfix`, then merge this temporary branch back into `X1`. It would avoid bringing commits from branch `A` into `X1`, at the cost of a few (potential) conflicts (or certainly more than a few if it's a somewhat big feature and branch `B` contains many commits and/or heavy ones).

Comment: I must add that I hope you didn't hold your breath for this one... (but then again this is SO, hopefully someone will find this helpful at some point)